# Using fixures in Unit testing with Nodejs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, jestjs, fixtures

I'm working on a *Nodejs*, *MongoDB project*, and I want to write *unit tests for it using **Jest***, Let's assume that there are two schemas in my project: `User`, `Book`. What I need is a structure, or a way or a tool to solve these issues:

1. be able to load a bunch of data before each test, and clear it afterward (I want a fix and clear database state for each test)

   - it is better if the data is loaded from a JSON file.
2. I need to be able to specify the data I want to load for each test. for example, I only need fixtures related to User schema when I want to write unit tests for User API, so I don't want to load fixtures related to Book schema.
3. it would be a bonus point, but not necessary if the database used is the in-memory database instead of the real MongoDB database. (I want the tests to be fast)

so far I only have found some libraries that solve the first one, but not the second one.